# Puppet error : Could not create master.pid

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I've configure puppet server and client, when I run `puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize` on puppet server, I get following message,

```
Notice: Starting Puppet master version 3.8.4
Error: Could not run: Could not create PID file: /var/run/puppet/master.pid
```

what could be the possible solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server` indicates that the puppet agent was unable to contact the puppetmaster.

Ensure the puppet agent is configured with the puppetmaster's hostname or fully qualified domain name.
View `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` and in section `[main]`, confirm the value of `server` is correct.

Example configuration:

```
[main]
certname = puppetmaster01.example.com
server = puppet
environment = production
runinterval = 1h
strict_variables = true
trusted
```

In the above example the server name `puppet` must be the address of the puppetmaster.

See the [puppet configuration documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/config_file_main.html).

Second, ensure the puppetmaster's hostname or fully qualified domain name resolves to an IP address.  Fix your DNS if it does not resolve.

Use `dig` or another tool to ensure the name resolves correctly:

```
dig puppet
```

Lastly, check the firewall on the puppetmaster. Ensure all the required ports are allowed in the firewall configuration as specified in the [documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/latest/system_requirements.html).

- 8140 The Puppet master uses this port to accept inbound
  traffic/requests from Puppet agents. The PE console sends request to
  the Puppet master on this port. Certificate requests are passed over
  this port unless ca_port is set differently. Classifier group: “PE
  Master”
- 443   This port provides host access to the PE console. The PE
  Console accepts HTTPS traffic from end-users on this port. Classifier
  group: “PE Console”
- 61613     MCollective uses this port to accept    inbound
  traffic/requests from Puppet agents. Any host used to invoke
  commands must be able to reach MCollective on this port. Classifier
  group: “PE ActiveMQ Broker”
- 8142  Orchestration services uses this    port to accept inbound
  traffic/requests from Puppet agents.    Classifier group: “PE
  Orchestrator”

Answer (score 1):

try: `puppet agent --test --server localhost`

if that works then you don't have the `server` parameter set properly in your puppet agent config.

Comment: when I run `puppet agent --test --server localhost` I get `notice: Run of Puppet configuration client already in progress; skipping`

Comment: Means the puppet agent is probably already running as a service. See Mike's answer to look at the config. What I posted above is good for testing

Answer (score 0):

Check your network setup, DNS setup and puppet config setup.

The error suggests that the agent cannot connect to the master because it cannot resolve the hostname of the master.

This can be due to wrong networking setup (for example a wrong IP), missing DNS server entries or faulty DNS servers or due to a misconfiguration in the puppet.conf file on the agent.